# Why do I have to reconfigure X-server after every shutdown

Tags: xserver

Everytime I shutdown my computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and power it back on, Ubuntu does not seem to detect my video card, and I have to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks